# Rails model with multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a bit stuck on a problem, where I am trying to make a messaging system. Currently I have a "chat" model (with the attributes "name", author_id and receiver_id) and a "message" model (with the attributes "user_id" and "chat_id").

The reason for this is because I saw it in another stack overflow answer and I wanted only 2 people in a chatroom, not more. Problem now is that because there is one receiver and one author, its hard to interpolate over the messages, as I cannot write "@chat.receiver.id", as I dont know if the current_user is the receiver or the author of the chat.

All I really want is that I have a chat between 2 people, which only the 2 people can see. Is it better to not have a "chat" model, and just have a message model? Or is there a way to have an attribute for the chat where I can store multiple user_ids, to see who is in there and who not (this would be great as I could then do a group chat with more than 2 people"

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think you might want to consider having a "conversation" model that is just a join.  So it simply contains user ids of anyone in the chat.  Messages would belong to a conversation and a user.  There is no sender and receiver, that doesn't really make sense because both people would participate in the chat so they both send and recieve.

Comment: Yeah that sounds great! But how do you put multiple user ids into a single attribute?

Comment: You don't you have multiple records in the join table.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html would be a good place to start learning about setting up relationships and how to manage that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds like a database modelling problem! :)

The Chat model sounds good (representing a convo, or room?) but I wouldn't store the participants here (arguable you might have an "owner" that created it - this would be your author I think?)

Typically you would have a has_and_belongs_to_many (habtm) relationship between Chat and User, but you want to enforce a list of 2 people, so you need to define a habtm join model e.g 'Participation' that belongs to Chat and User and validates no more than 2 participants (can also store any other metadata about their participation).

Messages would then belong to Chat and to User and you can validate that the message is being created by one of the users participating.

I think that's your most future proof model (since you mention the possibility of opening it up to more people later).

Below is some outline code to show the model relations and how you might validate...

```
class User
  has_many :chats
  has_many :participations
  has_many :messages
end

class Chat
  belongs_to :user # the author  
  has_many :participations
  has_many :messages
end

class Participation
  belongs_to :chat
  belongs_to :user

  validate :validate_participant_limit

  def participant_limit?
    participations.count < 2
  end

private 
  
  def validate_particpant_limit
    return unless :participant_limit?
    errors.add(:user_id, "Maximum participants reached") 
  end    
end

class Message
  belongs_to :chat
  belongs_to :user

  validate :validate_chat_participant

  def by_author?
    message.user == message.chat.user
  end

private

  def validate_chat_participant
    return unless chat.participations.map(&:user).include? user
    errors.add(:user_id, "User is not in this chat") 
  end    

end
```